# How do I specify a custom special folder for a setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I know how to add a special folder to "File System on Target Machine" and make it a custom folder.  I create one called "Program X" for example.  The msi gets passed a parameter, 'ProgramXInstallPath', at the command line which is set to 'D:\SomeFolder\ProgramX'.  I use the method from the following link to get and set the parameter in another project that I have for custom actions.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/command_lines_setups.aspx

How do I set the location of my custom folder to the value of the parameter, 'ProgramXInstallPath' that was passed into the msi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around some more with my setup project and the "Property" property on Special Folders and ended up getting no where.  I found a solution of setting the "Default Location" for the Special Folder to the parameter that I pass into the msi, '[ProgramXInstallPath]'.  Make sure that you have the square brackets.